Are zero, zeros & zeroth considered as determiners or adjectives?
Are zero, zeros & zeroth considered as determiners or adjectives?
Cambridge dictionary says these are adjectives. But I am confused yet. Because one, two, three, first, second... are determiners. Why not these?

zero books = No books, adjective. The zero [noun] in the answer  is wrong. [I am still confused.]

This is the same question you asked in ELU: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/627506/adjective-vs-determiner

These are numerals.  "Zero" is a rather special numeral, but it is best categorised with "one", "two" etc.
Numerals are a distinct class, there are two forms of numerals in English, cardinal and ordinal.  Numerals, like adjectives and determiners/determinatives (there is variation in terminology), be part of an NP and are often (like adjectives and determinatives) placed before a noun.
In some descriptions of English grammar, numerals are included in the determiners, and I've also seen them lumped in with the adjectives.  There is a case for considering them as a sub-category of determiner, but they are distinct in a number of ways.
There is more than one way to describe English grammar, so you should expect to see variation from one text to another, and indeed from one StackExchange answer to another.

There isn't the clear distinction that you might think. Determiners can function adjectivally, just as can some nouns can do so.
Not sure which Cambridge dictionary you are looking in, but the primary definition of 'first' in the Cambridge online dictionary says that it is an ordinal number and a determiner.
Numbers act as determiners when they identify the place of something in a numbered sequence. That can be a number (eg "Jaws 2") or an ordinal (eg "Richard the Third").
The distinction between determiner and adjective in many cases is subtle, and it often depends on how the term is being classified in different grammatical frameworks. For example, if you said "this is my first time traveling abroad", there is no sequence (there may never be a second time) so arguably the ordinal is just an adjective adding detail to the noun 'time'. But if you were talking about a series of events and referred to them as "the first time", "the second time" etc then arguably this is a determiner by the definition above.
